# PHP displaying Wordpress array.

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

**If you know nothing about Wordpress but know how to display everything stored in an php array (at least in my case) - please answer. I'll appreciate!**

I've an PHP array that keeps lists of categories. But I have no idea how to display its contents.

This code:

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category;
```

Outputs:

> Array

What I want to do is to display first item in the array.

I've also tried:

1. echo $category[0]->cat_name
2. echo $category[1]->cat_name

Where the cat_name was "cat_name", "Folio" (my custom post type name), "type", "types" and "my_folio_cat". Everything outputs nothing (even not "Array" text).

I'm registering taxonomy like that:

```
register_taxonomy("my_folio_cat", array("folio"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Type", "singular_label" => "Type", "rewrite" => true));
```

Comment: from what I recall of `get_the_category`, `$category[0]->cat_name` should do it. Try `var_dump($category)` to see the structure of the variable, and it would help to edit your post and add that info here. It's not just arrays here, just to note - some of this info is stored in a PHP object.

Comment: You should use `name` instead of `cat_name` (which is deprecated, and only currently implemented for back-compat)

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($array);
```

You can also take a look at `var_dump()` (not intended for reading) and `var_export()` (even less so).

If you'd like to print things nicely, you could iterate over the array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Key is '.$key.' for value '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` I do believe.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Note that `var_dump()` prints variables, whereas `print_r()` is intended to be a human readable representation of the variables

Comment: Oh I've only ever used var_dump but then again I may not be human.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler I don't find var_dump to be unreadable. It only provides more detail than print_r.

Answer (score 0):

try `var_dump($category);` instead `echo $category;`

Answer (score 0):

array access is echo $arrayname[0];

make var_dump($array) and you can see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

Based of your explanation, I guess you use custom taxonomy instead of general post category. For custom taxonomy you should use [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function.

So perhaps the code should:

```
$cats = get_the_terms($post, 'my_folio_cat');

// display the first category name    
if(!empty($cats)) {
    echo $cats[0]->name;
}
```